# Index manteinance: does the order of processing make a difference?

Tags: sql-server, performance, index

I have an 800GB SQL Server Enterprise database with very bad performance. So, based on a few scripts I found online I'm creating a job on my SQL database to maintain our indexes. Most of my tables have a clustered index and 3 or 4 non-clustered.

- Does it make any difference the order in which the indexes are being
  rebuild/reorganized?
- Is it the same if I first reorganize the clustered index and then the
  nonclustered ones or if I do it the other way?

Comment: Are you sure that fragmentation is your problem ? See this : `Why Defragmenting Your Indexes Isn’t Helping with Brent Ozar`  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iEa6_QnCFMU

Comment: Order doesn't matter for rebuild/reorganize (but does for drop/create). Fragmentation is unlikely to be to root cause of severe performance problems; I'd first look for index and query tuning opportunities.

Answer (score 1):

> Does it make any difference the order in which the indexes are being
>   rebuild/reorganized?

As commented by @Dan Guzman it does not matter. But if your rebuilding and  free disk space is limited I suggest you start from small to bigger ones (among the one qualify based on whatever criteria you are using).  Reason explained here:

[Disk Space Requirements for Index DDL Operations.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/disk-space-requirements-for-index-ddl-operations)

Very good tips for other considerations.

[Should You Rebuild or Reorganize Indexes on Large Tables? (Dear SQL DBA Episode 19)](https://littlekendra.com/2016/10/13/should-you-rebuild-or-reorganize-indexes-on-large-tables-dear-sql-dba-episode-19/) by Kendra Little.

> Is it the same if I first reorganize the clustered index and then the
>   nonclustered ones or if I do it the other way?

Yes it same because the clustered keys, which are the record locators in the NC indexes, aren’t changed because you rebuild the index.

Answer (score 1):

On SQL Server 2000, if you rebuilt your **non-unique** clustered index, all non-clustered indexes based on that **non-unique** clustered index would be automatically rebuilt. That's because the uniquifier changed during the rebuild.

This is not the case on SQL Server 2005 and higher, or if they are just being reorganized.

For index and statistics maintenance automation, I recommend using [Ola Hallengren's Maintenance Solution](http://ola.hallengren.com), to manage this for you. You might also use [Minionware's Reindex](http://minionware.net/products/reindex/), also free.

**Side note**: updating statistics regularly is (in my experience) more beneficial from a time and resource point of view than rebuilding indexes. Thus, I would do daily statistics updates, and defer heavy index maintenance to a longer schedule (weekly or monthly) *if required*. The level of fragmentation will dictate this, because rebuilding may not be necessary.